# SharePoint 2010 Dialog Missing Content

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, branding, customization

I have customized a SharePoint 2010 master page, all is working except dialog boxes are displaying empty. For example, if I try to add users to a group the dialog comes up, but no content is in the box.

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

use the developer tools and see if there is your custom css is blanking the form up. As you may know that you can remove css rules from the developer tool on the spot without changing the master page itself to see the effect (just to save you any hassle)

Comment: That was one of the first things I did, however it is not a css problem. I believe I may have missed some elements that the dialog box depends on. I used the ShareBoot 2010 Bootstrap template, that is the only thing I cannot get working